# How can a multithreaded application go ANR without any main thread operations?

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin

I'm developing an application which uses a started Service (Sticky) to do http fetching and parsing every few minutes. The service does all operations within a new Thread and the main thread only exists to start the service. How then can my application go ANR from within the service when no operation is done from the service outside the new Thread? The application is developed in Xamarin for Android and makes uses of the HTMLAgilityPack and WebRequests.

Also, if applicable, how do I debug the source of the ANR?

Thanks.